# pandas index StringMethods loses index

Tags: python, pandas

I've just noticed that string operations on the index of a Pandas DataFrame doesn't maintain the index, so assigning the result back to the dataframe is kind of awkward.  for example (and the case where I noticed it):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
  [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]],
  index=['a11','b12','c13'])

df['num'] = df.index.str.extract('([0-9]+)')
```

gives me:

```
     0  1  num
a11  1  2  NaN
b12  3  4  NaN
c13  5  6  NaN
```

as the index has been lost and just reverts back to `[0,1,2]`

it took a bit of debugging to realise this index loss is why I was getting NaN's, but once I did it was obvious that I could just do:

```
df['num'] = df.index.str.extract('([0-9]+)').set_index(df.index)
```

is this right, or are there other methods that maintain the index?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to use the `expand` argument:

```
df['num'] = df.index.str.extract('([0-9]+)', expand=False)
```

from the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html):

> **expand : bool, default True**
>
> If True, return DataFrame with one column per capture group. If False, return a Series/Index if there is one capture group or
>   DataFrame if there are multiple capture groups.
>
> New in version 0.18.0.

Answer (score 1):

How about use `assign`?

```
df.assign(num=df.index.str.extract('([0-9]+)').values)
```

Comment: just using `.values` works, e.g. `df['num'] = df.index.str.extract('([0-9]+)').values`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `expand` command to give same desired results as yours using:

```
df['num'] = df.index.str.extract('([0-9]+)', expand=False)
```

`expand=False` returns series or index or dataframe, since you have only one extracting group you can use expand parameter.